# How to prevent multiple queries in this case?

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres. I have 2 tables.
PS : week starts from monday.

```
Time (id (bigInt), startOfWeek (Date), startOfMonth (Date), startOfQuarter(Date), day (Date) ...)
```

and

```
User (id (bigInt), timeId (FK --> Time), total (Int)).
```

Given 2 dates (start and end), a dimension (day / week /month / quarter), I need to find out the total for each day / week / month / quarter.

Example :

```
Time (id (1), startOfWeek ('07-13-2015'), startOfMonth ('07-01-2015'), startOfQuarter('07-01-2015'), day ('07-13-2015') ...)

Time (id (2), startOfWeek ('07-13-2015'), startOfMonth ('07-01-2015'), startOfQuarter('07-01-2015'), day ('07-14-2015') ...)

//for 22nd july.
Time (id (3), startOfWeek ('07-20-2015'), startOfMonth ('07-01-2015'), startOfQuarter('07-01-2015'), day ('07-22-2015') ...)

User (id (11), timeId (1), total (5)).
User (id (12), timeId (2), total (10)).
...
```

Given 2 date values start and end, and dimension 'd' (W /M /Q etc) how can I write a query to fetch values from User table like :

```
'07-13-2015' 100
'07-20-2015' 122 etc
```

The problem is the startOfWeek field will be same for 7 days. I need to get the value of only the first row in User table where startOfWeek changes.

> I could do it using multiple queries :
>
> 1. get all startOfWeeks from Time table
> 2. for each startOfWeek, query User table and do first(..)

Is there a better / more efficient solution?

Comment: You can use [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) to generate the dates you want and then join it with the 2 tables. In the first table (and please add the names of the tables in the question!) is there one row for each date?

Comment: @ypercube - The table names are `User` and `Time` :P. Yes, in the `TIme` table, there is one row for each date (but week, month and quarter start dates could be same). You mean I should generate values and then do a join?

Comment: As an aside, it's not a very wise idea to name tables with keywords.

Comment: @dezso - They are not real names :).. They are *placeholder* names.

Comment: We prefer *real* names since those are often part of the problem. And unsuspecting readers might get confused with syntactically invalid identifiers. We also like to see the query you tired, even if it's not working. And your version of Postgres, obviously.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - I have given exact details and my attempt [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106795/removing-duplicate-values-from-sql-query-result)

Comment: You should have edited this question and add the info here. No reason for a duplicate question.

Comment: @ypercube - Actually, I was able to proceed further based on your input (Thank You! ), but I got stuck [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106795/removing-duplicate-values-from-sql-query-result)