# Remove duplicate values from query result

Tags: postgresql, database-design, greatest-n-per-group

I am using Postgres 9.3.9. I have 2 tables :

**f_agent :**

```
CREATE TABLE f_agent (
  f_agent__id bigserial NOT NULL,
  f_agent__total_users integer NOT NULL,
  f_agent__dim_time_id integer NOT NULL,
  .... other unnecessary columns
);
```

**dim_time :**

```
CREATE TABLE dim_time (
  dim_time__id bigserial NOT NULL,
  dim_time__date date NOT NULL,
  dim_time__month_start_date date NOT NULL,
  dim_time__week_start_date date NOT NULL,
  dim_time__quarter_start_date date NOT NULL,
  dim_time__year_start_date date NOT NULL,
  dim_time__guid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
);
```

Now, `f_agent__dim_time_id` field in `f_agent` is FK referencing `dim_time__id` of `dim_time`.

My `dim_time` table has a date and its related `week_start_date`, `month_start_date` etc. For example: if `dim_time__date` is `14-07-2015` then `dim_time__week_start_date` will be `13-07-2015` (monday is start of week) and `start_of_month` is `01-07-2015` (always the first).

I have to find  `f_agent__total_users` from f_agent given a date range and a dimension (week / month / quarter).

What I've tried:

```
SELECT dim_time__week_start_date, f_agent__total_users 
FROM f_agent
JOIN dim_time 
    ON f_agent__dim_time_id = dim_time__id 
WHERE dim_time__week_start_date IN (
    SELECT generate_series('2015-07-06', '2016-07-03', '7 day'::interval)
);
```

The output:

```
 dim_time__week_start_date   f_agent__total_users
"2015-07-13";                      3
"2015-07-13";                     33
"2015-08-10";                     12
```

But I only need the first value in case 2 `week_start_dates` are same. The output I am expecting here is:

```
 dim_time__week_start_date   f_agent__total_users
"2015-07-13";                      3
"2015-08-10";                     12
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide sample data that illustrates the problem (as insert statements or even better as an sqlfiddle)?

Comment: @Lennart - The problem is in `f_agent` table, I have lot of FK references / constraints, so you will need several insert statements (thats why I am leaving those details :(  )

Comment: Also, please include the FK code with your table declarations. It makes life easier for those who are trying to help you.

Comment: It's not clear why you are expecting 3 here. To be accurate wouldn't you want the SUM of all the results within the period, i.e. 2015-07-01 would be 36? You're not really getting duplicates at all.

Comment: @ypercube - My bad.. I edited the question... Had copied and pasted results from a different query

Comment: @JamieSee - I don't want the sum.. I could get the sum and use a `group by` to prevent duplicate week_dates .. But what I want is - *in case of duplicate week_start_dates` , the first row should be used for that group.

Comment: I think you should try running your query with `WHERE dim_time__date IN (...)`

Comment: @ypercube - But I am checking for *weeks*. Given a start date and end date, I need to find total counts on given dates (on weekly basis, it would be every monday) . I could do this in java, but it would be a lot slower (also occupies lot of memory)

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Does it not give you what you want?

Comment: @ypercube - It doesn't... It gives only one column i.e the first one

Comment: I meant you only change the `WHERE`, not the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25791/discussion-between-thelostmind-and-ypercube).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way - if your version is 9.3+ - is to use the `LATERAL` syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  generate_series('2015-07-06', '2016-07-03', '7 day'::interval) AS d (dt)
  , LATERAL  
    ( SELECT fa.*, dt.*
      FROM dim_time AS dt
        INNER JOIN f_agent AS fa
          ON fa.f_agent__dim_time_id = dt.dim_time__id
      WHERE dim_time__week_start_date = d.dt
      ORDER BY dt.dim_time__date
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS dt ;
```

Tested at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a4b74/13).

Answer (score 4):

The super quick fix will be to apply `DISTINCT ON()` to your query.

## DISTINCT ON

Postgres allows the use of the `DISTINCT` qualifier, but allows it to be applied across a subset of your returned columns from your `SELECT` query.

In this case, you could simply rewrite your query as

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(dim_time__week_start_date) 
dim_time__week_start_date, f_agent__total_users 
FROM f_agent
JOIN dim_time 
ON f_agent__dim_time_id = dim_time__id 
WHERE dim_time__week_start_date IN (
SELECT generate_series('2015-07-06', '2016-07-03', '7 day'::interval)
);
```

Refer to the [Postgres documentation on `DISTINCT ON` within `SELECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html) for more info.

***A word of caution:***  By applying `DISTINCT ON`, it will keep only the first row, ***regardless*** of how the order is returned by your query.  Unless you apply some `ORDER BY` criteria, you may end up with inconsistent results!

In effect, you could run the query once and get `f_agent__total_users` as `3`, but run it later and get `f_agent__total_users` as `33`.  I would ***highly recommend*** some additional predicate criteria to ensure proper and consistent results are returned.

Comment: Awesome !!!.. Thannks a ton :)

Comment: Sure thing. :-)

Comment: It's non-standard.. Also, what do you mean by *In effect, you could run the query once and get f_agent__total_users as 3, but run it later and get f_agent__total_users as 33*?  (Thanks nevertheless :P). How can I ensure that *consistent* results are returned?

Comment: Use `ORDER BY dim_time__week_start_date, dim_time__date`

Comment: As stated, you must apply an `ORDER BY` as both myself and ypercube have suggested.  What exactly the `ORDER BY` should be depends on your application.  It is hard to provide guidance. The consistency of your results will depend on the inclusion of an `ORDER BY` whether you choose my solution or ypercube's.

Answer (score 4):

### DB design

Simplify your design ***radically***:

```
CREATE TABLE dim_time (
  dim_time__id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  -- assuming PK
  dim_time__date date NOT NULL,
  dim_time__guid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
);
```

These columns are functionally dependent and just noise bloating your table:

```
dim_time__month_start_date date NOT NULL,
dim_time__week_start_date date NOT NULL,
dim_time__quarter_start_date date NOT NULL,
dim_time__year_start_date date NOT NULL,
```

The redundant columns wouldn't even help performance of the query at hand. See below.
Use the function [**`date_trunc()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) instead, that will be faster overall.

If you really need a table of this form add a `VIEW`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW dim_time_plus AS
SELECT *
     , date_trunc('week',    dim_time__date)::date AS dim_time__week_start_date
     , date_trunc('month',   dim_time__date)::date AS dim_time__month_start_date
     , date_trunc('quarter', dim_time__date)::date AS dim_time__quarter_start_date
     , date_trunc('year',    dim_time__date)::date AS dim_time__year_start_date
FROM   dim_time
```

Or even a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-creatematerializedview.html) if you insist on having the redundant columns persisted.

I see no reason for `bigserial` *and* a `guid` in that table. There are not nearly enough days in known time to justify the big data types. There must be other considerations not in the question. Or use `integer` (`serial`) instead of `bigint` (`bigserial`).

It also contradicts your FK from `f_agent.f_agent__dim_time_id`, which is defined `integer`, not `bigint`.

From what we see here, your whole DB design might be improved.

### Query

Similar to what @ypercube and @Chris provided, but based on the decluttered design and improved.

#### For *many rows* per time range

```
SELECT x.d AS dim_time__week_start_date, l.f_agent__total_users
FROM  (SELECT d::date FROM generate_series(date '2015-07-06'
                                         , date '2016-07-03'
                                         , interval '7 day') d) x
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT f.f_agent__total_users 
   FROM   dim_time d
   JOIN   f_agent f ON f.f_agent__dim_time_id = d.dim_time__id
   WHERE  d.dim_time__date >= x.d
   AND    d.dim_time__date <  x.d + 7  -- or + interval '1 month' for month etc
   ORDER  BY d.dim_time__date, d.dim_time__id, f.f_agent__id  -- to break ties
   LIMIT  1
   ) l;
```

Details for this technique:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

#### For *few rows* per time range

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1) 
       date_trunc('week', d.dim_time__date) AS dim_time__week_start_date
     , f.f_agent__total_users 
FROM   f_agent f
JOIN   dim_time d ON f.f_agent__dim_time_id = d.dim_time__id
WHERE  d.dim_time__date >= date '2015-07-06'
AND    d.dim_time__date <  date '2016-07-03' + 7
ORDER  BY 1, d.dim_time__date, d.dim_time__id, f.f_agent__id;
```

Details for DISTINCT ON:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

I added presumed PK columns of each table (`d.dim_time__date, f.f_agent__id`) in the `ORDER BY` to get a deterministic result. Replace that with what ever expression you actually need to use to break ties.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cdcec/2)

*If* *every* row in `dim_time` is referenced by at least one row in `f_agent`, you can join to `f_agent` later to make it a bit faster.

#### Indexes

To make these queries fast add [multicolumn indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html). Most likely candidates:

```
CREATE INDEX dim_time_foo_idx ON dim_time (dim_time__date
                                         , dim_time__id);
CREATE INDEX f_agent_foo_idx ON f_agent (f_agent__dim_time_id
                                       , f_agent__id
                                       , f_agent__total_users);
```

Details depend on undisclosed cardinalities and constraints and the full picture of your situation.

Comment: Nice. I had the same (>= d AND  < d+7) in my first draft. About the design, not sure if the extra columns could help in some queries (if indexed). The `dim_time__id` seems useless though as the `dim_time__date` can be used as PK (and FK in the `f_agent` table).

Comment: @ypercube: If the redundant values are used in other queries, we could use functional indexes or substitute with similar techniques as displayed here. Or, if all else fails, use the MV I mentioned. As for the relational design: What's presented here does not add up on its own.